# The location of the plugin file obtained by vscode is inconsistent with the file location of the plugin file obtained by gitbash. How to uninstall?

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-bash, vue-cli-4

For example, I have installed vuecli here, the vue version I got from the vscode terminal is installed in C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@vue\cli, and I opened the vue version obtained by gitbash It is installed in the custom directory of my d drive (where the environment variable is configured).

I installed the plug-in in the vscode terminal to a custom directory of my D drive, but I used the plug-in installed in the c drive. How should I uninstall the installation at the location of the c drive .
(direct uninstall will uninstall the installation of my d drive, and the c drive installation cannot be updated, and deleting the corresponding file will report an error)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried using npm uninstall ./ file location successfully. Finally solved it, the original method is so simple